# 'anyObject' is not convertible to 'Dictionary<key, value>]'

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

Hi I want to get an object type dictionary by using NSUserDefaut :

```
var favoritePlace = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savePlace")!  as [Dictionary]
```

but i get the error 'anyObject' is not convertible to 'Dictionary]'

i also try :

```
var favoritePlace = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savePlace")!  as [Dictionary<String, String>()]
```

but it's not work, too.
Anyone know how can I do this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both tries are syntax errors.

To cast to a dictionary: `Dictionary<Type, Type>` or `[Type : Type]`

So by doing

```
var favoritePlace = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savePlace")! as [[String: String]]
```

or

```
var favoritePlace = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savePlace")! as [Dictionary<String, String>]
```

Comment: This is converting your dictionary to NSArray!